# OpenLDAP @SUFFIX@ notation

Tags: configuration, ldap, openldap

I've started researching LDAP and started following a tutorial to at least start familiarizing with it. While doing that, I noticed that there is an odd (for me) notation in the `/usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf` file on my computer, namely `@SUFFIX@` and other things surrounding by the at sign. I think that this is supposed to be interpreted as some kind of a variable or substitution point, but any search on Google turned out nothing, as they ignore special characters.

How should I interpret this and where can I change it?

Comment: What tutorial? It isn't mentioned in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapd.conf).

Comment: This tutorial. http://www.fosteringlinux.com/2010/03/getting-started-with-openldap-part-1/ It's not in the manpages. Simply something that I found on google.

Comment: "@SUFFIX@" does not appear anywhere on that page. What are you talking about?

Comment: Not there. In the actual `slapd.conf` that is on my computer. I may have worded the question too ambiguously. Sorry about that.

Comment: Blimey. 'Ambiguously' isn't the word. 'Wrongly' springs to mind. At a guess, you're expected to replace @SUFFIX@ by whatever your actual DIT suffix is, throughout. Or some configuration utility is supposed to do it for you.

Comment: Well, I have no idea. As I said, I'm a total newbie to LDAP. My course of action was thus: I started following the tutorial, noticed that there is no `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf` file and searched for it throughout the filesystem. I found it under `/usr/share/slapd` and opened it... I'm a bit confused, to be honest, of how and where everything should go.

Comment: I suggest you start again and find out how it is supposed to be installed and configured, instead of trying to do it by hand.

Comment: I supposed that I would find that out through the tutorial. But I got confused because my distro and his aren't compatible (I think). Thanks for the time spent on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about [the `slapd.conf` template from the Debian package](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-openldap/openldap.git/tree/debian/slapd.conf). @SUFFIX@ and the other tokens in that file are replaced at configure time by [the maintainer scripts](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-openldap/openldap.git/tree/debian/slapd.scripts-common#n459).

(The package also contains [a similar template for dynamic configuration](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-openldap/openldap.git/tree/debian/slapd.init.ldif); `slapd.conf` is no longer used.)